# Get selected key/value of a combo box using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select, key-value

Please, how can I get the selected key and value of a HTML select combo box using jQuery?

```
$(this).find("select").each(function () {
    if ($.trim($(this).val()) != '') {
        searchString += $.trim($(this).val()) + " "; //This gives me the key. How can I get the value also?
    }
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 100, accepted):

I assume by "key" and "value" you mean:

```
<select>
    <option value="KEY">VALUE</option>
</select>
```

If that's the case, this will get you the "VALUE":

```
$(this).find('option:selected').text();
```

And you can get the "KEY" like this:

```
$(this).find('option:selected').val();
```

Comment: Bala, you can get key using, $(this).find('option:selected').val();

Answer (score 25):

This works:

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
<option value="1">a</option>
<option value="2">b</option>
<option value="3">c</option>
</select>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Button" />

$('#button').click(function() {
    alert($('#foo option:selected').text());
    alert($('#foo option:selected').val());
});
```

Answer (score 9):

```
<select name="foo" id="foo">
 <option value="1">a</option>
 <option value="2">b</option>
 <option value="3">c</option>
  </select>
  <input type="button" id="button" value="Button" />
  });
  <script> ("#foo").val() </script>
```

which returns 1 if you have selected a and so on..

Answer (score 4):

```
$(this).find("select").each(function () {
    $(this).find('option:selected').text();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#elementName option").text();
```

This will give selected text of Combo-Box.

```
$("#elementName option").val();
```

This will give selected value associated selected item in Combo-Box.

```
$("#elementName option").length;
```

It will give the multi-select combobox values in the array and length will give number of element of the array.

**Note**:*#elementName*  is id the Combo-box.

Comment: Please provide some context when providing a solution - how does this code address the issue and resolve it?